# if x:, vs if x == True, vs if x is True

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I have searched in vain for an answer to my *exact* question. Basically, with Python 2.7, I have a program running a series of geoprocessing tools, depended on what is reqested via a series of True/False variables that the user adjusts in the script e.g.

```
x = True

if x:
    run function
```

However, I have now discovered that x does not need to be literally "True" for the function to run. For example:

```
In: x = True
    if x:
        print True

Out: True

In: x = 123
    if x:
        print True

Out: True

In: x = 'False'
    if x:
        print True

Out: True

In: x = False
    if x:
        print True

Out:
```

So any value other than False appears to evaluate to True, which would not be the case for if **x == True** or if **x is True**. Seeing as PEP 8 strongly recommends only using the **if x:** variant, can anybody explain why this behaviour occurs? It seems that if x: is more a test for "if x is not False" or "if x exists". With that in mind, I believe I should be using if x is True: in this case, despite what PEP 8 has to say.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following values in Python are false in the context of `if` and other logical contexts:

- `False`
- `None`
- numeric values equal to 0, such as `0`, `0.0`, `-0.0`
- empty strings: `''` and `u''`
- empty containers (such as lists, tuples and dictionaries)
- anything that implements `__bool__` (in Python3) to return `False`, or `__nonzero__` (in Python2) to return `False` or `0`.
- anything that doesn't implement `__bool__` (in Python3) or `__nonzero__` (in Python2), but does implement `__len__` to return a value equal to 0

An object is considered "false" if any of those applies, and "true" otherwise, regardless of whether it's actually equal to or identical with `False` or `True`

Now, if you've arranged that `x` is necessarily one of the objects `True` or `False`, then you can safely write `if x`. If you've arranged that the "trueness" of `x` indicates whether or not to perform the operation, regardless of type, then you can safely write `if x`. Where you can write that you should prefer to do so, since it's cleaner to read.

Normally, if it is allowed for `x` to take the value `True` then you're in one of those two cases, and so you would not write `if x is True`. The important thing is to correctly document the meaning of `x`, so that it reflects the test used in the code.

Python programmers are expected to know what's considered true, so if you just document, "runs the function if `x` is true", then that expresses what your original code does. Documenting it, "runs the function if `x is True`" would have a different meaning, and is less commonly used precisely because of the style rule in PEP8 that says to test for trueness rather than the specific value `True`.

However, if you wanted the code to behave differently in the case where `x` is an empty container from the case where it is `None`, then you would write something like `if x is not None`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. In my case, while I only would want the user to use True or False, and no other values, the code is documented enough to follow PEP 8 and leave my if x: statements as they are.

Comment: [docs.python.org - truth-value-testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add a short example where those 3 tests differ:

```
def test(x):
    print(x, ":", bool(x), x == True, x is True)

test("something")
test(1)
test(True)
```

The output (pretty formatted):

```
# "something" : True False False
#           1 : True True  False
#        True : True True  True
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 'False'
x = 123
```

Are both `True`

[Other truth values.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

The document explains other values.

As far as the PEP8 reason, its far more semantic to read `if this_file_is_green`

Comment: +1 for the link, without realising it, I had been looking at the tutorial for an older release of Python without this much detail.

Answer (score 1):

Other falsey values include `0`, `''`, `[]`. You should just use the `if x:` version.

Answer (score 1):

It goes without saying that you should write code that does what you need. But in most cases, you simply don't need to say `== True` or `is True`, because you don't need to distinguish `True` from other "truthy" values. So it's recommended to leave that out for simplicity.

The case where you definitely should use `== True` or `is True` is when you *do* need to distinguish `True` from other truthy values.

In your example, do you care about the difference between `True` and `123`? That would tell you which way to code it.

One thing about coding `== True` or `is True`: it will raise a minor red flag when other developers read your code. They won't think it's wrong, they will just wonder why it's there and will want to know why it's important to treat `True` differently from other truthy values in this particular case.

In other words, if you don't need it, it's best not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to say

```
if x:
   ...
```

is considered a feature. You can also specify when the test should be considered to pass or not for user defined classes (just define the method `__nonzero__` in Python 2.x or `__bool__` in Python 3).

For example for strings and containers like lists, dictionaries or sets the test `if x ...` means "if x is not empty".

Note that the rationale is not that this allows less code to write, but that resulting code is easier to read and to understand.

If you like instead to write `if x is True ...` have you considered to go farther down that path to `if (x is True) is True ...` or `if ((x is True) is True) is True ...` ? :-)

Comment: You know that the value of `x is True` must be either `True` or `False`, whereas you may not know the same thing of `x`. So that's what stops the infinite recursion in the desperately unlikely scenario that `True` has special meaning distinct from other true values :-)

Comment: I understand what you mean, although I'm not sure why anybody would code "if (x is True) is True". It would be like using "if (x == False) == False". I agree with Steve on this one.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, `if a:` and `if a==True` are not giving the same output for values different to 1. Here are some snippets of code to demonstrate the different behaviors:

### with `a=1`

```
a=1
if a==True: 
    print (a,"True")
else:
    print (a,"Not True")

output> (1,True)
```

```
a=1
if a: 
    print (a,"True")
else:
    print (a,"Not True")

output> (1, True)
```

### with `a=2`

```
a=2
if a: 
    print (a,"True")
else:
    print (a,"Not True")

output> (2, True)
```

```
a=2
if a==True: 
    print (a,"True")
else:
    print (a,"Not True")

output> (2, Not True)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use `if x` ,it means it  has to evaluate x for its truth value.But when you use `x ==True` or `x is True`.It means checking whether type(x)==bool and whether x is True.

**attention** : `x is True` is no equal to `bool(x)==True`

when you use `x is True` , you are checking the id of x and True.