# What does "if condition" mean, when the condition is not a statement?

Tags: python

I'm learning about functions at the moment, and this one came up as an example:

```
def a(x, y, z):
     if x:
         return y
     else:
         return z
```

I'm not exactly sure what `if x` actually means, though. `x` is just a parameter, not a statement, so how can it be true or false?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420934/python-booleans-if-x-vs-if-x-true-vs-if-x-is-true

Comment: The condition is *never* a statement. A statement is an action such as `y = 0`. The condition is an *expression*, e.g. `len(my_list) > 1`, which has some value. `x` is also an expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It checks if x is "truthy", which means that it shouldn't be :

- None
- False
- Zero
- Empty

As an example :

```
if 1 and True and "string" and ["list"] and {'key' : 'value'} and\
    not None and not 0 and not False and not "" and not [] and not {}:
  print "I understood truthiness!"
# => I understood truthiness!
```

Comment: Why, then, if I type `2 == True`, does the console output `False`?

Comment: 2 is not `True`, it is only "truthy" :  `bool(2)==True`

Comment: @SteveSmith: Because `True`, when evaluated as an integer, means `1`, and `1` is not the same as `2`. An operation between an integer and a logical value (Boolean) is usually treated as an operation between integers. To convert an integer such as `2` to a logical value, use `bool(2)`, which evaluates to `True`, while `bool(0)` is `False`.

Answer (score 3):

In python, everything has a truth value associated with it. For example, all numbers except `0` are *truthy* (evaluate to `True` in a conditional statement), and `0` is *falsey* (evaluates to `False` in a conditional statement). This is because of the `__bool__` method in the each class.

For example:

```
In [140]: def f(x,y,z):
   .....:     if x:
   .....:         return y+z
   .....:     else:
   .....:         return y-z
   .....:     

In [141]: f(True, 3, 4)
Out[141]: 7

In [142]: f(False, 3, 4)
Out[142]: -1

In [143]: f(1, 3, 4)
Out[143]: 7

In [144]: f(2, 3, 4)
Out[144]: 7

In [145]: f(863, 3, 4)
Out[145]: 7

In [146]: f(-24, 3, 4)
Out[146]: 7

In [147]: f(0, 3, 4)
Out[147]: -1
```

Similarly, empty collections (lists, sets, dictionaries, strings, tuples, etc) are falsey, while non-empty collections are truthy.

Answer (score 2):

If only a variable is given as the condition in an `if` statement, the condition will be evaluated by Python's standard truth testing procedure. You can try the method out for yourself in the console with the `bool` method, which maps directly to it. Here are some examples:

```
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1,2,3])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, any non-zero value, non-empty string/list/set, etc is considered as `True` where as `None`, empty-string/list/set etc and `0` are considered as `False` by `if`. This evalution is done by the [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool). Below is the illustration.

```
my_list = ['a', 100, None, '', 0, {}, {'a': 1}, [], ['a']]
for item in my_list:   # Iterate over each value and checks the condition
    if item:
        print item, ": True", ", Bool value: ", bool(item)
    else:
        print item, ": False", ", Bool value: ", bool(item)
```

which prints (explicitly formatted for readability):

```
a :        True ,       Bool value:  True
100 :      True ,       Bool value:  True
None :     False ,      Bool value:  False
 :         False ,      Bool value:  False
0 :        False ,      Bool value:  False
{} :       False ,      Bool value:  False
{'a': 1} : True ,       Bool value:  True
[] :       False ,      Bool value:  False
['a'] :    True ,       Bool value:  True
```

As you see, execution of `if` is mapped to the `bool()` value.

Comment: also empty list, set, dict...