# Flake8 error: E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'

Tags: python, if-statement, flake8

```
if user.item.purchase.status == True:
```

...produces an error when checking with flake8:

> E712 comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'

`status` has three valid values: Undefined, True, and False.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python booleans - if x:, vs if x == True, vs if x is True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420934/python-booleans-if-x-vs-if-x-true-vs-if-x-is-true)

Comment: Long story short, `if user.item.purchase.status` checks for truthiness, while `if user.item.purchase.status is True` checks if the value is exactly `True`. The linter wants you to decide to use one or the other. The linked answer has more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well in case `status` is a *boolean*, then it is strange to write `expr == True`, since `True == True` is `True`, and `False == True` is `False`, we can simply write `expr` instead.

If on the other hand `status` is something that is *not* per se a *boolean*, then the comparison will try to check if the object *value equals* to `True`, which can be different, but usually it is "strange" that some object is equal to `True` or `False`. For example `1 == True` holds, but `1` and `True` are *different* objects.

In case `status` is something that can be a non-boolean, and you want to check if status is *really* `True` (so not the *value* equality, but *reference* equality), then the `is` check can be used, since `exp1 is exp2` checks if the two variables refer to the *same* object.

If you however write an expression as condition, like `if expr`, then Python evaluates the *truthiness* of that expression. For example the truthiness of a non-empty list is `True`, whereas for an empty collection, it is usually `False`. Since the truthiness of `True` and `False` are `True` and `False` respectively, there is thus no need to write `== True` in that case.

I think here `status` is probably a `BooleanField`, so in that case you can write:

```
if user.item.purchase.status:
    # ...
    pass
```

Comment: Why does flake8 recommend 'if cond is True', when PEP8 clearly states that 'if cond' is best, 'if cond == True' is wrong but 'if cond is True' is worse?

Comment: @Svenito: the two are not equivalent. `if x is True` means it will suceed if `x` is indeed the boolean `True`, whereas `if x` will suceed if `x` has *truthiness* True, this means any non-zero integer, any non-empty list, tuple, string, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The error msg is saying you to use this syntax.

```
if user.item.purchase.status:
    #Do Stuff
```

You do not need to mention `== True`