# Variable Syntax Error

Tags: python, variables, syntax, pygame, syntax-error

So.THIS:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import sys

itworks = True

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

bootpng = pygame.image.load('bootimage.png')
bootpng = pygame.transform.scale(bootpng, (600, 600))
backgroundmenu = pygame.image.load('Menu_background.png')
backgroundmenu = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundmenu, ((600, 600))
button = pygame.image.load('technical_information_button')
button = pygame.transform.scale(infobut, ((130, 80))
screen.blit(bootpng, (0, 0))
time.sleep(3)

while itworks == True:
    screen.blit(backgroundmenu, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(tekbutton, (470, 520))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ecent.type == pygame.QUIT:
            itworks = False

    #    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
    #x, y = event.pos
    #if ball.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

is my code. Buuut.. for SOME reason python says "Invalid Syntax" at variable button, line 15*. I really don't know what to do about it, I tried a lot of things, so I hope I can get help from here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete an extra bracket.

Replace: `button = pygame.transform.scale(infobut, ((130, 80))`

with: `button = pygame.transform.scale(infobut, (130, 80))`

In Python there should always be an opening bracket and closing bracket.

**Edit:**

Just to add on, I strongly suggest to replace your `while itworks == True` into `while itworks is True`. More information can be seen here: [Boolean identity == True vs is True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276610/boolean-identity-true-vs-is-true)

Basically, that `if` statement may not give the expected result in some cases due to the equality not comparing references. It is simply the 'pythonic' way of doing things.

Comment: Uhh.. ok I just found out the problem I had that bracket thing and also above it, now it works (well not really it says it can't read the file, but that's something I can fix..) and uhh.. how do you mark answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

A little more elaboration.

The problem was that you had the extra parenthesis make in line `button = pygame.transform.scale(infobut, ((130, 80))`.

The reason you got `Syntax Error` is python thought you were truing to type `variable=(variable_declared="in parenthesis")`, which is a Syntax Error.

If you commented all of the code after `button = pygame.transform.scale(infobut, ((130, 80))` you get a more explanatory error:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import sys

itworks = True

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

bootpng = pygame.image.load('bootimage.png')
bootpng = pygame.transform.scale(bootpng, (600, 600))
backgroundmenu = pygame.image.load('Menu_background.png')
backgroundmenu = pygame.transform.scale(backgroundmenu, ((600, 600))
##button = pygame.image.load('technical_information_button')
##button = pygame.transform.scale(infobut, ((130, 80))
##screen.blit(bootpng, (0, 0))
##time.sleep(3)
##
##while itworks == True:
##    screen.blit(backgroundmenu, (0, 0))
##    screen.blit(tekbutton, (470, 520))
##    for event in pygame.event.get():
##        if ecent.type == pygame.QUIT:
##            itworks = False
##
##    #    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
##    # Set the x, y postions of the mouse click
##    #x, y = event.pos
##    #if ball.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
##
##    pygame.display.flip()
##
##pygame.quit()
```

Now, the code throws the error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` which is directly caused by the extra parentheses.

That said, I would actually advise you to change `while itworks == True:` to `while itworks:` (opposed to @UltraGold's answer).

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20421262/8524178) and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) (Python's Style Guide) the most 'Pythonic' approach is `while itworks` versus `while itworks == True:` and actually **further discourages** `while itworks is True` as this is actually a different test that may cause unexpected errors (the problem that @UltraGold was trying to address).